# Pivot Table with Time Series Data / Rows-to-Columns / Re-Org Data into Single Row

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pivot, pivot-table

I have some time series data that I need to re-organize. It looks like this:

```
Accounts   2015   2016  2017 
Account1   100    150   200
Account2   220    240   260
Account3    80     60    50
```

I need it all grouped into 1 row with the accounts moving from the rows to columns like this:

```
         Account1_2015  Account2_2015 Account3_2015 etc
Single-row   100           220               80
```

How would I do that in Pandas? I'm thinking of pivot tables, but not sure precisely how I would go about doing this, since most examples with pivot tables don't involve reorganizing all the data into a single row like this.

Comment: seems like you just need to transpose

Comment: That would work, except I don't actually want to move the columns to rows; only the rows to columns. Rather, I want everything combined into one row on the column side.

Essentially, I have a massive amount of data and I'm combining a bunch of different datasets together and each dataset should be 1 row in the new dataframe.

Comment: Have you try melt ?

Comment: Try `df.melt('Accounts').set_index(['Accounts', 'variable']).T`

Comment: @user3483203 That works! Thanks!